# Raspberry Pi wrapper script called by cron fails

Tags: bash, cron

this is my first question (in that forum) so please be patient ... ;-)
To the problem:
I'm trying to run a binary on an raspi that crashes by chance once in a few hours. As the binary gives its output usually to stdout, I'm trying to use it with screen and pipe its output to a file. Doing so, I've written a small wrapper script which is called by cron every five minutes. My idea was, that, if the output file don't changes over a certain period, than the process is killed and restarted.
Here 's my /etc/crontab:
`*/5 * * * * pi bash /home/pi/myscript.sh >/dev/null 2>/dev/null`

Here 's the myscript:
    #!/bin/bash

```
# Input file
FILE=/home/pi/output.txt
# How many seconds before file is deemed "older"
OLDTIME=300
# Get current and file times
CURTIME=$(date +%s)
FILETIME=$(stat $FILE -c %Y)
TIMEDIFF=$(expr $CURTIME - $FILETIME)

# Check if file older
if [ $TIMEDIFF -gt $OLDTIME ]; then
   #echo "File is older, do stuff here"
        bash /home/pi/check_myscript_is_running.sh
fi
```

Here 's the script that checks:
    #!/bin/bash

```
case "$(pidof processname | wc -w)" in

0)  echo "Restarting process:     $(date)" >> ~/output.txt
screen -dm /home/pi/binary -l output.txt &
;;
1)  # all ok
;;
*)  echo "Removed double process: $(date)" >> ~output.txt
kill $(pidof process | awk '{print $1}')
;;
esac
```

But obviously the last script doesn't start the process anew and I'm getting mails from the cron:

```
From pi@raspberrypi Fri Jul 01 16:42:25 2016
Return-path: <pi@raspberrypi>
Envelope-to: pi@raspberrypi
Delivery-date: Fri, 01 Jul 2016 16:42:25 +0200 
Received: from pi by raspberrypi with local (Exim 4.84_2)
    (envelope-from <pi@raspberrypi>)
    id 1bIzeD-00007c-0A
    for pi@raspberrypi; Fri, 01 Jul 2016 16:42:25 +0200
From: root@raspberrypi (Cron Daemon)
To: pi@raspberrypi
Subject: Cron <pi@raspberrypi> pi   /home/pi/startprocess.sh
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/pi>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=pi>
Message-Id: <E1bIzeD-00007c-0A@raspberrypi>
Date: Fri, 01 Jul 2016 16:42:25 +0200

/bin/sh: 1: pi: not found
```

I don't have a script startprocess.sh and I thought that with the output pipe the mails would be suppressed ...
But the main question is: Why is the script that should restart the process if the output file has'nt changed for five minutes not running ?
Cheers and regards,

JD.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right: In some environments the cron PATH is not set, so calling up `pi` in your crontab leads to the error mail you get.

Try to fully qualify your script call with an absolute path, e.g. like this:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/script/pi /usr/bin/bash /home/pi/myscript.sh >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```